# Querying for any entries after traversing multiple conditional includes in EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Consider the following data model:

- A Principal has a number of Roles (many-to-many);
- Roles grant multiple Permissions (many-to-many);

Now i want to use LINQ to determine whether a Principle has a permission, i.e. whether he is in any Roles that possess this permission.
Usually I would go for `AnyAsync` on the join table for cases like this , but since I am traversing more than one join table I am really struggling. I initially came up with this:

```
    var query = context.Principals
        .Where(p => p.Id == "SomeUUID")
        .Include(p => p.Roles)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Permissions
        .Where(p => p.Name == "SomePermission"));
```

But now I would have to traverse, probably in-memory, the attached Roles through the Principal again to search for `Any` Permission.

Is there a way I can smoothly apply this check within the same query?

EDIT: Here is the generated SQL to complement Parks'(bottom) answer in comparison:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM [Principals] AS [a]
          INNER JOIN (
              SELECT [a1].[Id], [a1].[Description], [a1].[DisplayName], [a0].[RoleId], [a0].[PrincipalId]
              FROM [PrincipalRoles] AS [a0]
              INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [a1] ON [a0].[RoleId] = [a1].[Id]
          ) AS [t] ON [a].[PrincipalId] = [t].[PrincipalId]
          INNER JOIN (
              SELECT [a3].[Id], [a3].[Name], [a2].[RoleId], [a2].[PermissionId]
              FROM [RolePermissions] AS [a2]
              INNER JOIN [Permissions] AS [a3] ON [a2].[PermissionId] = [a3].[Id]
          ) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[RoleId]
          WHERE ([a].[PrincipalId] = "SomePrincipal") AND ([t0].[Name] = "SomePermission")) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END

SELECT CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM [Principals] AS [a]
          WHERE ([a].[PrincipalId] = "SomePrincipal") AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM [PrincipalRoles] AS [a0]
              INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [a1] ON [a0].[RoleId] = [a1].[Id]
              WHERE ([a].[PrincipalId] = [a0].[PrincipalId]) AND EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM [RolePermissions] AS [a2]
                  INNER JOIN [Permissions] AS [a3] ON [a2].[PermissionId] = [a3].[Id]
                  WHERE ([a1].[Id] = [a2].[RoleId]) AND ([a3].[Name] = "SomePermission")))) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a principal has a Role in Roles that has a Permission in Permissions you can use the following Where condition:

```cs
var result = await context.Principals
    .Where(p => p.Id == "SomeUUID" && p.Roles.Any(r => r.Permissions.Any(x => x.Name == "SomePermission")))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If `result` is null then either the Principal did not exist or did not have the permission you checked for. If `result` still needs to have the navigation properties then you can add the include statements originally included in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just went for `AnyAsync` as i don't need to retrieve the results at all. My original query was just what I expected the result to look similar as.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for this query:

```cs
var hasPermssion = context.Principals
    .Where(p => p.Id == "SomeUUID")
    .SelectMany(p => p.Roles)
    .SelectMany(r => r.Permissions)
    .Any(p => p.Name == "SomePermission");
```

Here is the generated SQL statement:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM [Principals] AS [a]
          INNER JOIN (
              SELECT [a1].[Id], [a1].[Description], [a1].[DisplayName], [a0].[RoleId], [a0].[PrincipalId]
              FROM [PrincipalRoles] AS [a0]
              INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [a1] ON [a0].[RoleId] = [a1].[Id]
          ) AS [t] ON [a].[PrincipalId] = [t].[PrincipalId]
          INNER JOIN (
              SELECT [a3].[Id], [a3].[Name], [a2].[RoleId], [a2].[PermissionId]
              FROM [RolePermissions] AS [a2]
              INNER JOIN [Permissions] AS [a3] ON [a2].[PermissionId] = [a3].[Id]
          ) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[RoleId]
          WHERE ([a].[PrincipalId] = "SomePrincipal") AND ([t0].[Name] = "SomePermission")) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END
```

Comment: I think you can use Where instead of Any in this query.

Comment: Not sure, we have to check that Principal has permission, and its is overkill to retrieve records.

Comment: True, but it’s only retrieving the matching permission.  Either should work.  In any case I think the SelectMany or it’s LINQ equivalent of stacking FROM is the simpler pattern.

Comment: It is easy to change `Any` to `FirstOrDefault`. Benefit here that SQL Server will be happy: only joins and one EXISTS.

Comment: Yes, `AnyAsync` suffices. I do believe this is the more concise solution, but i noticed that it performs marginally worse than @Jeffrey Parks solution, at least on very little available data. Might this be due to the inner joins' `SELECT` including all columns when querying Roles/Permissions? Is there a way projection can be applied here to squeeze a little more performance out of `SelectMany`?

Comment: I have not checked what EF generated in such case. It should be simple query with EXISTS and joins.

Comment: Well, what can I say. Somewhere EF will learn how to create effective queries. All these subqueries has to be removed.

Comment: It's really not that much of a big deal (~750ms vs. ~ 650ms for 1000 executed queries including context instantiation). This might come out different in a realistic environment with more data. I was just wondering about the necessity of fetching the entire row within those inner `SELECT` statements.

Comment: It is limitation of current EF Core translator. There should be no fields in SELECT at all. But don't worry SQL Server will not fetch row at all. EXISTS should return boolean.

Comment: Anyway, consider to cache permissions information in memory. It will be really painful to grab it on every operation.